# how to convert rupees to words in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

how to convert rupees to alphabets asp.net ?
I have tried the below code but didn't work.
var formatted = d.ToString();

```
    if (formatted.Contains("."))
    {
        //If it contains a decimal point, split it into both sides of the decimal
        string[] sides = formatted.Split(".");

        //Process each side and append them with "and", "dot" or "point" etc.
        return NumberToWords(Int32.Parse(sides[0])) + " and " + NumberToWords(Int32.Parse(sides[1]));
    }
    else
    {
        //Else process as normal
        return NumberToWords(Convert.ToInt32(d));
    }
```

Note :I need in the below format

eg :23,234.50 - twenty three thousand two thirty four rupees and 50 paise.

Comment: Define "didn't work".  Did you remember to implement a method called `NumberToWords` or did you think the compiler was going to do that for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string amount = "58,765.50";//Here you will replace your value.
amount = amount.Replace(",", "");
string []sides = amount.Split('.');
string rupees = NumberToWords(int.Parse(sides[0])) + " And " + NumberToWords(int.Parse(sides[1])) + " paisa";
```

Here you will an amount which you want to convert into words. If your amount contains `,` you need to replace it so that it can be converted into `int`. You also need to split the amount on `.` so that you can get `rupees` and `paisa` seperate. Than you need to pass `rupees` and `paisa` to the function and concatenate them for final output.

[Here](http://string%20amount%20=%20%2258,765.50%22;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20amount%20=%20amount.Replace(%22,%22,%20%22%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20string%20[]sides%20=%20amount.Split('.');%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20string%20rupees%20=%20ConvertNumberToWords(int.Parse(sides[0]))%20+%20%22%20And%20%22%20+%20ConvertNumberToWords(int.Parse(sides[1]))%20+%20%22%20paisa%22;) is the link which you can use for the method `NumberToWords`